# Proving an approximate angle trisection by compass and straightedge

Tags: circles, plane-geometry, angle

My 70 year old father has given the below explanation. Can some one please verify or point out deficiencies if any.

> The geometrical problem of trisecting any given angle by using compass and a straight unmarked edge is impossible. Many have tried but couldn't achieve the perfect one over a period of nearly two centuries. l hereby submit a near perfect but simple way of construction as under.
>
> [image]
>
> **Given.** In a circle with center $O$, $\angle POB$ is any angle to be trisected. $A$-$O$-$B$ is diameter extended towards $Q$.
>
> **Construction.** Join $AP$. By construction, take $C$ as midpoint of $AP$. From $C$ we draw a transversal at an angle of one fourth of given $\angle POB$, which is possible by geometrical construction. (Eg, if the measure of $\angle POB$ is, say, $12x$, then $\angle PCR$ is of measure $3x$.) Our transversal meets a line parallel to diameter in $R$ and diameter extended in $Q$. Join $PQ$ and $RA$, which gives us a parallelogram $PRAQ$.
>
> If you measure the $\angle PQO$ by protractor, you will find that it's measure is nearly one third of the measure of the $\angle POB$.

**Proof.** I have tried my level best to prove it geometrically but was not successful, however found the proof of impossibility.

Let this time the angle be $90^\circ$ (i.e., a right angle) and the radius of the circle be unity (i.e., one). Then $\angle PQO$ must be of $30^\circ$, which means segments $PQ$ and $QO$ must be $2$ and $\sqrt3$, respectively. Also, segments $MQ$ and $MO$ equal to $1$.

$\triangle APO$ is an isosceles right-angled triangle, measure of base angles are $45^\circ$, each which means segment $AP$ is $\sqrt2$. $C$ being midpoint of $AP$, segment $AC$ is $\sqrt2/2=1/\sqrt2$. Thus, all segments $PR$, $PC$, $AC$, and $AQ$ are $1/\sqrt2$ each. (We can prove this being opposite sides of parallelogram.) Therefore, the length of $QO$  is $AO+AQ=1+1/\sqrt2$. Certainly $\sqrt3$ is not equal to $1+1/\sqrt2$. thus the proof of impossibility.

Comment: Showing a particular construction that does not achieve trisection is certainly not a way to prove impossibility. As if you said that there are no perfect squares because 65535 is not a perfect square.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_trisection#:~:text=Angle%20trisection%20is%20a%20classical,unmarked%20straightedge%20and%20a%20compass.

Comment: "If you measure the $\angle PQO$ by protractor.." No, just no. Also, this is a specific instance of the problem.

Comment: @Kousthub Dhok: For which case is it exact and when is it most inaccurate?

Comment: By my calculations, if $\angle BOP =12x$, then 
$$\cos\angle BQP=\frac{1+2\cos 6x}{\sqrt{5+4\cos 6x}}$$ That is, the construction amounts to the assertion 
$$\cos\frac13\theta \;\approx\; \frac{1+2\cos\frac12\theta}{\sqrt{5+4\cos\frac12\theta}}$$ As series, this says
$$1 - \frac1{18}\theta^2 + \frac1{1944}\theta^4 + \cdots\approx 1 - \frac1{18}\theta^2 - \frac1{233280}\theta^6 -\cdots$$ so the approximation isn't *terrible*.

Comment: It is worth noting that your transversal is parallel to the line bisecting angle $\angle BAP$.

Answer (score 3):

The construction can be simplified to this:

[image]

(To see why: $\angle BAP=\frac12\angle BOP$ by the [Inscribed Angle Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle). In the construction, $\overline{QC(R)}$ makes an angle of $\frac14\angle BOP=3\theta$ with $\overline{AP}$. Thus, $\triangle ACQ$ has an interior angle of $3\theta$ and an exterior angle of $6\theta$, so its other angle is $3\theta$: that is, it's isosceles with $\overline{AC}\cong\overline{AQ}$. Consequently, locating $Q$ is a simple matter of transferring $C$ to the extended diameter via a circle about $A$.)

---

To understand the nature of the approximation ...

[image]

By [Thales' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27s_theorem), $\angle APB$ is a right angle. Therefore, $|AP|=|AB|\cos6\theta$, so that $$|AQ|=|AC|=|CP|=r\cos 6\theta \tag1$$

If we drop a perpendicular from $P$ to $B$, we find from right triangle  $\triangle PDQ$ that
$$\tan\angle Q = \frac{r\sin 12\theta}{r\cos6\theta+r+r\cos12\theta} =
\frac{2\sin6\theta\cos6\theta}{\cos6\theta+2\cos^26\theta}= \frac{2\sin 6\theta}{1+2\cos6\theta} \tag{2}$$

Thus, the construction amounts to the assertion

> $$\tan\frac13\phi \;\approx\;\frac{2\sin\frac12\phi}{1+2\cos\frac12\phi} \tag{3}$$

As series, this says
$$\color{green}{\frac13\phi}+\frac1{81}\phi^3+\frac2{3645}\phi^5+\cdots \;\approx\;
\color{green}{\frac13\phi}+\frac1{72}\phi^3+\frac{13}{17280}\phi^5+\cdots \tag{3'}$$
Also, as noted in a comment to the original question, we have
$$\cos\frac13\phi \;\approx\; \frac{1+2\cos\frac12\phi}{\sqrt{5+4\cos\frac12\phi}} \quad\to\quad
\color{green}{1 - \frac{\phi^2}{18}} + \frac{\phi^4}{1944} + \cdots\;\approx\;
\color{green}{1 - \frac{\phi^2}{18}} - \frac{\phi^6}{233280} -\cdots \tag{4}$$
(The reader can consider other forms.) So, all in all, the approximation doesn't seem *terrible*. A thorough error analysis is left as an exercise.